# Is this called "Circular Reference"?

Tags: design-patterns, observers

Having the Observer pattern, we all know that based on its class diagram, the SUBJECT uses a reference to the OBSERVER.  Meanwhile, the OBSERVER has a reference to SUBJECT in order to register or remove itself.

Is this a "Circular Reference"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you describe it, it is a case of circular reference. However, note that in [the full pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), `Observer` is an abstract class / interface, which has one or more concrete implementations. `Observer` in some variations knows nothing about `Subject` (although its subclasses may refer to it), in other variations it may depend on an `Observable` interface or directly on `Subject`. However, `Subject` knows only about `Observer`, not its concrete subclasses.

So the reference is not (necessarily) circular.

Comment: "Reference" is way too overloaded a term.  Even in the pure form of the pattern, a cycle in the object references typically exists (unless the observer tosses the reference to the subject, which usually doesn't happen in practice).

Comment: @Mark, the term is indeed overloaded. IMO here we are talking about dependencies between interfaces/classes. In this context I maintain that there is no circularity in Observer per se.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it's a circular reference.  It's a cycle in the graph of references.

Using the term "circular references" sometimes occurs when talking about more harmful things though, particularly when you have circular *dependencies* (e.g. A needs B to compile, but B needs A to compile).

A circular reference in itself isn't harmful (e.g.: a circular linked list).